# Confirm dialog in web automation using c# webbrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, automation, webbrowser-control, browser-automation

I need to automate website which has Submit function.

Submit button triggers a JavaScript function which trigger a Confirm dialog.

Able to automate click by:
HtmlElement.InvokeMember("click");

But not able to automate/give OK on confirm dialog.

Tried different approaches but didn't work.

Enter key option also not working:
HtmlElement.InvokeMember("click");
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");

Is there any way to approach this in c# webbrowser?

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will do the magic:**

```
 public void AcceptAlert()
 {
        IAlert alert = GetAlert();
        alert.Accept();
        WaitForPageLoading(); //this implement by yourself
 }

 public IAlert GetAlert()
 {
        try
        {
             IAlert alert = Driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
             return alert;
        }
        catch (NoAlertPresentException)
        {
             // no alert to dismiss, so return null
             return null;
        }
}
```